# Bootstrap grid - horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a page where bootstrap scrolls any items horizontally rather than vertically example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red;">item1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:blue;">item2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:green;">item3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">item4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:red;">item5</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:blue;">item6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:green;">item7</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:yellow;">item8</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above example I am trying to have 'item4' & 'item8' visible when scrolling left/right only.

However bootstrap is placing these items below 'item1' & 'item5' respectively

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the numbering of your divs.

Bootstrap's grid size is 12, so a col-sm-4 will render max 3 per line (4 + 4 + 4 = 12).

You'll need to use col-sm-3, which has 25% of the container, and allows to show 4 per line (3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 12).

In resume, try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:red;">item1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:blue;">item2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:green;">item3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:yellow;">item4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:red;">item5</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:blue;">item6</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:green;">item7</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:yellow;">item8</div>
  </div>
```

Here's Bootstrap Grid explanation:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood it, but if you want to 'hide' items 4 and 8, you'll probably need to use Bootstrap's `table`, or else with javascript :)

Comment: Using the above would not result in any overflow. I was looking for a way to do it with the grid layout. Maybe table is the way to do it